# How to make reference beetween two schema mognose node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to make refrence in my MERN app beetwen two schema Movie and Seanse.
This is my Movie Schema:

```
 const Movie = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  movieDescription: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  movieImgUrl: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  seanses: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Seanse",
    },
  ],
});

export default mongoose.model("Movie", Movie);
```

And this is my Seanse schema:

```
const Seanse = mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    require: true,
  },
  hour: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  movie: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Movie",
  },
  bookings: {
    type: Array,
    require: true,
  },
});

export default mongoose.model("Seanse", Seanse);
```

But when i requests for movies in postman I see empty array, this is my code for geting all movies :

```
async findAll(req, res) {
    const movies = await Movie.find().populate({
      path: "seanses",
      model: "Seanse",
    });
    return res.status(200).send({ data: movies });
  },
```

This is what I recive at Postman :

```
 {
      "seanses": [],
      "_id": "5f5bea1993df462974d63e66",
      "title": "Hacker 5",
      "movieDescription": "Lorem Ipusm",
      "movieImgUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZGJiZGMwMmUtMjdiZS00M2QzLWE3YjAtNTU2MjQ2ZDE3NDE1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTc5OTQwMzk@._V1_.jpg",
      "__v": 0
    }
```

Of course, I have previously created seanse in which I entered the id of an existing movie in the "movie" field

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose always adds 's' to the end of model name, so you should rename `Movie` to `Movies` and `Seanse` to `Seanses`.